# How can I add data to my dropdown list box in ASP.NET VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How can I add a data to my drop down list came from database?
My code is this.
And when I try using this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [renovationproject]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
    <br />
```

Using Dropdownlist input web control:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"          DataTextField="tasks" DataValueField="workid">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

It got errors in a webpage that says controls are not allowed to be put here.
I only have an empty dropdown right now.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DdLocation" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: What is the error message (specifically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to add data.  You can put them in there literally `<asp:listitem>`; Or here are some basic ones: http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_databinding.asp

You can also look into creating a `<asp:datasource>`.  I recommend you do this with the wizard first (in desing view, you should have a little arrow block near the dropdown list -- start with "choose data source".

You can also bind with a datatable in your code behind.  Google keywords asp:dropdownlist, databind(), dataadapter, dataset, datatable.

Comment: This is what I got in wizard "SqlDataSource1" and nothing happens.

Comment: OK -- try deleting the datasource, and also delete the attribute *DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"* from your dropdown list.  Then try to run the wizard again.